# passing self to another classes function in self's function

Tags: python, class, self

I have two classes, the first one has a function move(creature, board). Then in the creature class there is a function that calls move, so how do I pass the current creature to the move function while in the creature class? Should it just be move(self, self.board), because when I try that I get a "Undefined variable from import: 
 move" error?

Here's the relevant code:

Creature:

```
class creature: 
    def __init__(self, social, intelligence, sensory, speed, bravery, strenght, size):
        self.traits = [social, intelligence, sensory, speed, bravery, strenght]
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.hunger = 10
        self.energy = 30
        self.shelter = 0
        self.dominance = 0
        self.boardSize = size - 1
        self.SOCIAL = 0
        self.INTELLIGENCE = 1
        self.SENSORY = 2
        self.SPEED = 3
        self.BRAVERY = 4
        self.STRENGTH = 5
 ...
 def performAction(self, action, location):
       ...     
       if action == "storeFood":
          food = location.vegetation
          location.vegetation = -1
          simulation.move(self, self.shelter)
          self.shelter.foodStorage += food
       ...
```

Simulation:

```
class simulation():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.creatures = {creature.creature():"", creature.creature():"", }
        self.map = land.landMass
        self.lifeCycles = x
        self.runStay = ["rfl", "rbf", "rbl", "rbf", ]
        self.befriend = ["bbl", "bbf"]
        self.fight = ["fbl", "fbf", "bfl", "bff", "ffl", "fff"]
...    
    def move(self, creature, target):
            map[creature.x][creature.y].creatures.remove(creature)
            creature.energy -= abs(map[creature.x][creature.y].elevation - target.elevation) / creature.getSpeed() 
            target.creatures.append(creature)
            creature.x, creature.y = target.location
            ...
```

EDIT:
OK so I have somewhat solved the problem. Python requires that I have `simulation.simulation.map(self, self.shelter)` I'm assuming this means that it requires not just the class file but also an instance of that class. So the new question is do I have to make that instance somewhere else then pass it in? Or will this work with an instance of Simulation somewhere else?

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: I've added it, hopefully it makes sense

Comment: You need to post class and method signatures (the `class` and `def` lines). Why do you have two `simulation.move()` calls?

Comment: Oh sorry, the extra sim.move was just a test I forgot to remove.

Answer (score 2):

Inherit the `simulation` class into the `creature` class:

```
class Creature(Simulation): # I have inherited the functions from Simulation into Creature
    ...
```

Now instead of `simulation.move(self, self.shelter)`, you want:

```
self.move(yourparameters)
```

If you noticed, I capitalised your class names. [It's good to do so.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)

For more on inheritance in classes, take a look [at the docs].(http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)